# last day of the current month?

Tags: sql

i have to get the last day of the current month. how can i get

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182742/how-do-i-calculate-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql

Comment: Need to know the SQL implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set dateformat dmy

select dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(m, 1, '01-' + convert(varchar, month(getdate())) + '-' + convert(varchar, year(getdate()))))
```

add one month to the first of this month, minus one day.

Answer (score 10):

SQLite (sqlite3)

Compute the last day of the current month.

```
SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');
```

checkout this link as well if your using sqlite3
[sqlite datetime functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer, and used here: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-date-function/

Answer (score 4):

**SQLITE QUERY FOR CALCULATE 
NUMBER OF DAY IN A CURRENT MONTH**

```
select strftime('%d',datetime('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 second'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) AS Last_day_of_month FROM DUAL;
```

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) AS Last_day_of_month
```

Comment: this doesn't work in all cases, such as January 31. You add a month and get Feb 28/29; then subtract 31. Fails.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative: add a month to the date, then subtract the resulting day value of the new month:

`select day(dateAdd(d, -day(dateAdd(m,1,'2012-01-31')), dateAdd(m, 1, '2012-01-31')))`