# How do you calulate last day of the month from datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate the last day of the month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182742/how-do-i-calculate-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-sql)

New to SQL, but how would you determine the last day of the month value from datetime (trans_date).

Sorry just a dumb question, but rather than using current date can I specify a trans_date (date) from trans table

Comment: Just a note that if you are going to use this in for example a where clause, the first day of the next month is a lot more useful. Especially if you are using data type `datetime`. Ex. if you use `datetimecol < '20111001'` you will get the entire month but if you use `datetimecol <= '20110930'` you are not getting any rows for the last day of the month (except those created exactly at midnight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinal Dave has a good explanation here:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Keep in mind that if you're using SQL2008 you can `CAST( field AS DATE)` to get rid of the resulting time data.

Answer (score 5):

Easy, find the first of the following month and subtract 1 day.

eg,

```
DECLARE @dt AS DATETIME = GetDate();
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dt)+1,0))
```

EDIT: If you're selecting from a table just do this:

```
SELECT 
  SomeColumn,
  DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,SomeColumn)+1,0)) AS EndOfMonth
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Or just wait for Denali and use the EOMONTH() function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, probably a dumb question. But can you advise on how to use src_tran.tran_date value instead of GetDate() value

Comment: @PeleO - just replace `@dt` with `src_tran.tran_date`.

Comment: Already did that, however whenever it parses the declare will fail in that cannot assign value to variable

Comment: @Pele What's the declare got to do with it? I just used that to declare a value.. I take it you want to just select from a table... see answer update